# how Switch to another tab in tabhost with intent?

Tags: android, android-tabhost

I have 3 tab in tab host, I want switch to another tab with intent by click button..`

```
TabSpec Tab1 = tabhost.newTabSpec("Tab1");
    jadwalUser.setIndicator("Tab1", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.style1));
    Intent in1 = new Intent(this, Tab1.class);
    Tab1.setContent(in1);

TabSpec Tab2 = tabhost.newTabSpec("Tab2");
Tab2.setIndicator("Tab2", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.style2));
Intent in2 = new Intent(this, Tab2.class);
Tab2.setContent(in2);

TabSpec Tab3 = tabhost.newTabSpec("Tab3");
Tab3.setIndicator("Tab3", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.style3));
Intent in3 = new Intent(this, Tab3.class);
Tab3.setContent(in3);

tabhost.addTab(Tab1);
tabhost.addTab(Tab2);
tabhost.addTab(Tab3);`
```

I'm currently in Tab1, when this #Button1 clicked, i want to it to switch to Tab2 :

```
button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

public void onClick(View v) {
//What code here to switch to Tab2

}
}
```

Please help me, thanks..

Comment: whether you want to switch between activity or fragments?What your tabs containing?

Comment: b/w fragment.Nothing now

Answer (score 0):

You can call TabHost.setCurrentTabByTag(tabTag), where tabTag is the same string you used to create the tabSpec. So in your example to go to tab2 you would call:

```
tabhost.setCurrentTabByTag("Tab2");
```